# Managing test ssl certificates on dev environments

Tags: java, spring-boot, https, ssl-certificate, microservices

I have a Spring Boot web service, and I want to make it use https instead of http.

To this end, I have already created a keystore containing a self-signed certificate, and configured the server using spring boot properties.
The certificate has name localhost, to match the local environment.

Now I want to test it on a proper dev environment, but the certificate doesn't work any more, because the name needs to be the name of the environment.

What is the preferred way of dealing with this? Should I create a separate keystore/certificate per environment as well as a separate yml file with their respective properties?

Comment: Why not use letsencrypt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should create a new keystore for new environment as the (Common Name) CN field in keystore should match to your dev/test/prod environment. I assume your CN is localhost or loopback address when you created one for your local environment.

Alternatively, if you want to match based on wildcards such as *.test.abc.com you can do it using Subject Alternative Names(SAN).